# I want to print out the request using toast

Tags: java, android

I want to print out the request in android but when I use toast method it cannot resolve the method.

Here is my code,

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=0ac06623c66a3dd0e0e431f872a74710&wsfunction=core_user_create_users",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), client, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I want to print out the request.

Comment: What exactly you want to display in the toast??

Comment: i want to print out the request that  is being sent.

Comment: You can't display that client in your toast..do you want to dislpay the url?

Comment: can you please guide me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read documentation /implementation of AsyncHttpClient first. You won't get response like that. You need to Override onSuccess/onFailure methods for your AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

```
client.get("http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=0ac06623c66a3dd0e0e431f872a74710&wsfunction=core_user_create_users",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  new String(responseBody), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=0ac06623c66a3dd0e0e431f872a74710&wsfunction=core_user_create_users", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can pass the parameter ie the url directly assuming you want to show the url

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), client+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```